# Travis CI for terraform which uses terraform lint for syntax checking

Tags: travis-ci, terraform

I have a Terraform template along with two tfvars files. We'd like to source control the Terraform code and want to run terraform lint in Travis-CI before we merge the code.

I'm a beginner in Travis, does anyone have an example of `.travis.yml` file which I can use in order to download Terraform and run terraform lint to check for syntax errors before merging the pull request?

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: here is teh config.

Comment: {
  "language": "bash",
  "sudo": "required",
  "before_install": [
    "sudo curl -o  terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.9.8/terraform_0.9.8_linux_amd64.zip",
    "unzip terraform.zip",
   "mkdir ~/bin",
    "mv terraform ~/bin",
    "export PATH=\"~/bin:$PATH\""
  ],
  "install": [
    "sudo curl -sLo tflint.zip https://github.com/wata727/tflint/releases/download/v0.3.6/tflint_linux_amd64.zip",
    "unzip tflint.zip",
    "mkdir ~/tflint",
    "mv tflint ~/tflint",
    "export PATH=\"~/tflint:$PATH\""
  ],
  "script": [
    "tflint packerimage.tf"
  ]

Comment: I have added the above config and it worked fine for me but I need to send few arg's when I will execute the command "tflint packerimage.tf" but I need to hide it from user. Do you know the way to encrypt the keys or passwords in Travis?

Comment: update the codes and questions in your original post.

Answer (score 3):

This will check any files changed between your branch and the target branch.

travis.yml:

```
sudo: false
cache:
  directories:
  - "${HOME}/bin"
env:
  global:
  - PATH="${HOME}/bin
  - TMPDIR="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"
  - VERSION="0.11.0"
before_install:
  - if ! terraform version ; then
      mkdir -p "${HOME}/bin"
      pushd "${TMPDIR}" ;
      curl -sSL
        -o terraform.zip
        "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${VERSION}/terraform_${VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" ;
      unzip terraform.zip ;
      mv -v terraform "${HOME}/bin/terraform" ;
      chmod +x "${HOME}/bin/terraform" ;
      popd ;
      terraform version ;
    fi
script:
  - test/check-fmt.sh
```

check_fmt.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -z "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH" ]]; then
  BRANCH="$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH"
else
  BRANCH="master"
fi

exitcode=0
for file in $(git diff --name-only $BRANCH | grep .tf\$); do
  if [[ "$(terraform fmt -write=false "$file" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $file failed to pass terraform fmt"
    exitcode=1
  fi
done
exit $exitcode
```

Comment: `git diff --name-only $BRANCH` shows the names of the files with "changes you have in your working tree relative to the named". Since the CI is running a fresh clone, there'll be no changes.

Comment: @DanielSerodio you're doing a diff of the working branch from the target branch, so this will still show the files changed in your new branch compared to the target, defaulting to master.